# SQL: GROUP BY id having max date

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have two tables:

```
Table 1:
worker_number, first_name , last_name , clinic , doctor_type

1   BB BB  Z2 ENT
10  CC CC  Z3 ENT
4   DD DD Z4    Orthopedist
5   EE EE Z5Surgeon
8   AA AA Z1 ENT


Table 2:
worker_number, first_name , last_name , clinic , doctor_type, dt_date, patient_id

'1', 'BB', 'BB', 'Z2', 'ENT', '2017-02-01 10:00:00', '1'
'1', 'BB', 'BB', 'Z2', 'ENT', '2017-02-27 15:20:00', '1'
'8', 'AA', 'AA', 'Z1', 'ENT', '2017-02-28 08:40:00', '1'
```

Basically i want to get all rows from **table 1** that `doctor_type = "A"` ordered by the `dt_date` from **table 2** which has same `worker_number` and `doctor_type`

i tried to do somthing like:

```
SELECT `table 1`.worker_number, `table 1`.first_name, `table 1`.last_name, `table 1`.clinic
FROM `health`.`table 1`
LEFT JOIN `health`.`table 2`
ON `health`.`table 1`.worker_number = `health`.`table 2`.worker_number
order by `health`.`table 2`.dt_date desc
```

But i got the following output:

```
8   AA  AA  Z1
1   BB  BB  Z2
10  CC  CC  Z3
1   BB  BB  Z2
3   DD  DD  Z4
5   EE  EE  Z5
```

It works really good except for the BB is showing twice, How can i do group by for the maximum date?

excpected result:

```
8   AA  AA  Z1
1   BB  BB  Z2
10  CC  CC  Z3
3   DD  DD  Z4
5   EE  EE  Z5
```

Comment: A result set without a data set is like a stick without a lollipop. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate on the `worker_number` and sort on `MAX` (or `MIN` based on your needs) of the `dt_date`:

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    t1.worker_number, t1.first_name, t1.last_name, t1.clinic
FROM
    `health`.`table 1` t1
        LEFT JOIN
    `health`.`table 2` t2 ON t1.worker_number = t2.worker_number
GROUP BY t1.worker_number
ORDER BY MAX(t2.dt_date) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

This adds an extra column to your output. If you don't want that, you can wrap this query with another select query to select just the fields you want.

```
SELECT `table 1`.worker_number, `table 1`.first_name, `table 1`.last_name, `table 1`.clinic, max(`table 2`.dt_date) max_dt_date
FROM `health`.`table 1`
LEFT JOIN `health`.`table 2`
       ON `health`.`table 1`.worker_number = `health`.`table 2`.worker_number
group by `table 1`.worker_number, `table 1`.first_name, `table 1`.last_name, `table 1`.clinic
order by max_dt_date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

do the fatc you are not using aggregation function you shoudl need  the group by clause but you should use only DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      `table 1`.worker_number
    , `table 1`.first_name
    , `table 1`.last_name
    , `table 1`.clinic
FROM `health`.`table 1`
LEFT JOIN `health`.`table 2`
ON `health`.`table 1`.worker_number = `health`.`table 2`.worker_number
order by `health`.`table 2`.dt_date desc
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because the ORDER BY clause is only applied to the result set, not the complete data. You would therefore select the first unique row which may or may not be the max dt_date.

Comment: @morbidlycurious   the answer is for distinct but for mysql 5.6  and above the order by is not only for result set  .. anyway ...

Answer (score -1):

```
Select worker_number, first_name , last_name , clinic , doctor_type
from table1 t1
where doctor_type = "A"
Order By (Select dt_date from table2
          where worker_number = t1.worker_number 
             and doctor_type = t1.doctor_type)
```